# Cassandra - auto generate client query libraries in multiple languages given a cqlsh plain text query string

Tags: cassandra, code-generation, cqlsh, type-safety

I'd like to be able to auto generate client code in several languages given a `cqlsh` "`INSERT`" statement

So for instance if I have a "`INSERT`" statement like:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(C1,C2) VALUES (?,?);
```

I would be able to generate typesafe clients in several languages to "`SELECT`" against this exact query

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Real type safety will be possible only if you combine it with the table definition, etc. But there are no such tools exists right now...

For almost all languages the code structure be quite similar (pseudo-code):

```
// somewhere at beginning, only once
prepStatement = session.prepare(query)
// later in the code
boundStatement = prepStatement.bind(parameters)
session.execute(boundStatement)
```